# ASP.NET MVC3 Generate View Model including validation attributes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering if there is a way to generate a View Model from database table including validation (required,length,datatype). Of course I will edit it and enhance it.Otherwise it is a waste as I have to type in everything

Answer (score 0):

We are implementing a "Dynamic" approach to validation in one of our projects where the validation rules are encoded in a database table and we override GetValidators() in a custom implementation of DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider to inject custom and/or standard validation attributes. These can then be propagated to the client if we want them to. As for creating a viewModel from the existing database, you can use t4 files to read the db schema and generate classes for you and inject validation attributes on the model as it is being created.